# React.PropTypes array with specific length

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is it possible to use `React.PropTypes` to enforce length's on an array?

Here is a very simple case:

```
const TWO_NUMBERS = PropTypes.array; // i need this to be an array of two numbers
```

I know in javascript arrays are just objects so I tried this:

```
const TWO_NUMBERS = PropTypes.shape({
    0: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    1: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
});
```

However this keeps telling warning me `expected an object but got an array`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case you would need to write your own special *PropTypes* function which react provides you to do.

```
const TWO_NUMBERS = function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!Array.isArray(props.TWO_NUMBERS) || props.TWO_NUMBERS.length != 2 || !props.TWO_NUMBERS.every(Number.isInteger)) {
    return new Error(`${propName} needs to be an array of two numbers`);
  }

  return null
}
```

This would throw an error if `TWO_NUMBERS` isn't an *array*, isn't an *array* of two, and isn't an array of only integers.

You can get information about proptype functions here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#react.proptypes

Its at the bottom of that example block.

Comment: Thank you very much finalfreq! I'm new to proptypes and am absolutely loving this!

Comment: Where is the `isRequired` part?

Comment: @vsync since it returns an Error if any of those statements are false it acts the same as .isRequired. If you didn't want it to be required you could check for props.TWO_NUMBERS being null and if so just return null which passes proptype check.

Answer (score 9):

A custom function would be the correct approach here.

```
  const propTypes = {
    TWO_NUMBERS: arrayOfLength.bind(null, 2)
  }

  const arrayOfLength = (expectedLength, props, propName, componentName) => {
    const arrayPropLength = props[propName].length

    if (arrayPropLength !== expectedLength) {
      return new Error(
        `Invalid array length ${arrayPropLength} (expected ${expectedLength}) for prop ${propName} supplied to ${componentName}. Validation failed.`
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Than you very much garrett! I accepted final's solution as it came first. :(

Comment: Totally understand! Made my answer take any array length specification so it was a bit more reusable (and not just copying previous answer) so hopefully that helped!

Comment: It does so much! I really appreciate it brother! Especially the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer of @finalfreq, I came up with this. It handles two numbers (floats in this case) and can also be used as `arrayOf(twoNumbers)`. Not sure how to make it work like `twoNumbers.isRequired` yet...

Also I think the code is cleaner and easier to follow if you don't use the negation in the validation comparison.

```
import invariant from 'invariant';

function isValid(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 2 && value.every(Number.isFinite);
}

export default function twoNumbers(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (Array.isArray(props)) {
    props.forEach((item, index) => {
      invariant(
        isValid(item),
        `Array item index ${index} is ${item}, but needs to be an array of two numbers`
      );
    });
  }

  const value = props[propName];

  if (!value) return; // not required so could be null

  invariant(isValid(value), `${componentName} ${propName} needs to be an array of two numbers`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thijs for sharing! I am actually using flow type now adays, and am get a similar situation.

Comment: This is how to address the `isRequired` - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9125

Answer (score -5):

`PropTypes` checks for types not for attributes. Also, checking for `PropTypes` is disabled in production mode. That makes it impossible for `PropTypes` to check for ever changing array lengths during run-time.