# Best way to enforce preconditions of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I've created a React component (called `Parent` below) that takes in children and an array of labels as a prop. Its usage looks like this:

```
<Parent labels={['Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3']}>
    <Child1/>
    <Child2/>
    <Child3/>
</Parent>
```

I expect the number of labels in the array to be equal to the number of children that the component takes in.

What is the go-to way to enforce such a requirement? Some approaches that come to my mind would be using PropTypes, console.assert, or throwing an exception.

Comment: I don't think you can enforce array length in a linter context, but you can of course emit warnings when the component gets mounted and the lengths aren't the same.

Comment: Why bother with the children?  Why not just get it to accept an array of labels and get it to return the child components inside the parent component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.PropTypes array with specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659728/react-proptypes-array-with-specific-length)

Comment: @Etheryte Thank you for the link! But my main question is what the typical approach is to enforcing these sorts of conditions. Should PropTypes be used or is something like an assert or exception more appropriate?

Comment: It probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but it depends. If you're building a component library, it might be nice to warn the user if it happens in development mode. On the other hand, the user might have a good reason to do so, in which case the warning will be annoying. Shortly put, if you're 100% sure the labels are always necessary, I would recommend warning only in dev mode, but that's a very subjective opinion. Whether you use PropTypes or something else for that end is largely preference and coding style.